# C# How to choose button(X) if x = 1 and then it keeps adding?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to a do a program which manages tables in a restaurant.
When the button is clicked its supposed to check all the tables which are in an array if their status is clear,then highlight them by using another png.
ATTEMPTED FAILED CODE:

```
private void tblf_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (; z < 9; )
    {

            "button" + x +.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\\Users\\cents\\Desktop\\programming stuff\\C#\\TABLES\\sprites and shit\\clearHIGH.png");
            x += 1;
            y += 1;
            z += 1;

    } 
}
```

Comment: It sounds like your buttons should be in a collection or array. While you *could* access variables by name using reflection, that's not the best approach. (I'd also suggest that using fields for this is a little odd - is there any reason you're not using local variables?)

Comment: Agreed with @JonSkeet  also you're looping "while z is greater than 9" but you only ever increment z. When will it ever be lower than or equal to 9?

Comment: @JonSkeet What do you mean by putting the buttons in an array? Also there isn't any reason I'm not using local variables.

Comment: @Sichi the "while z is greater than 9" was a mistake,it was intended to be z>9

Comment: lol - 'sprites and shit', technical term I am not familiar with

Comment: I mean exactly what I say - instead of having `button1`, `button2` etc as separate variables, have a single variable `buttons` of type `List<Button>` or `Button[]`. That way you can access `buttons[x]` etc.

Comment: @JonSkeet Got it! Thanks,do you want to put it as answer so I can mark it as problem solving. Or shall I?

Comment: Feel free to add it yourself :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of having button1, button2 etc as separate variables, have a single variable buttons of type List or Button[]. That way you can access buttons[x] etc.
Credit
goes to Jon skeet. This was the solution after all!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Control.ControlCollection.Find`

```
Button button = this.Controls.Find("button"+x, false).Single();
button.Image = Image.FromFile(
    "C:\\Users\\cents\\Desktop\\programming stuff\\C#\\TABLES\\sprites and shit\\clearHIGH.png"
);
```

Comment: Why are you using `as`  when you're sure the cast will succeed? Also why `FirstOrDefault`  instead of `Single`?

Comment: Gives this error @John 
`Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS7036 There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'searchAllChildren' of 'Control.ControlCollection.Find(string, bool)' TABLES C:\Users\Philippos\Desktop\TABLES\TABLES\Form1.cs 243 Active`